# Remove index.php from URL of Laravel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.12 in Linux Mint.I am using LAMP stack. I would like to remove `index.php` from URL. My `mod_rewrite` apache module enabled.

My `.htaccess` file located in `public` folder and it contains following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I renamed the server.php in the Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to Laravel root folder. But it is not working.

I placed below code in `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  # Turn Off mod_dir Redirect For Existing Directories
  DirectorySlash Off

  # Rewrite For Public Folder
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But this not working.

Could anyone help me in this regard ?

Comment: "I renamed the server.php in the Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to Laravel root folder." makes me worry. Why did you not just configure your webserver to point to the public folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset anything you have changed back to the default.

In your apache virtual host configuration, ensure you have the DocumentRoot correct (it will be something like /var/www/html/laravelproject/public).

You should not need to make any changes to the .htaccess file in the public folder as this handles rewriting the url to remove index.php.  However, in some environments, I have had to add

```
RewriteBase /laravelproject
```

to the .htaccess in the public folder.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:

https://ma.ttias.be/remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-laravel/

To summarise, I added the following to the .htaccess file, directly below the existing index.php entry:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `httpd.conf` file, search for the line `DocumentRoot` and change it to where ever your `index.php` is. For example:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myappfolder/public"
```