# laravel 5.8 route with index.php redirect to root route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

how to `localhost:8000/index.php` route redirect to `localhost:8000` route or `404 status` in laravel 5.8
because `localhost:8000/index.php` broken all my css links and not beautiful URL and all internal links are  like this `localhost:8000/index.php/about`

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: Apache 2.4 (xampp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380202/remove-index-php-from-url-of-laravel you can follow this

Comment: problem are not same cause I don't rename the files .just call index.php in url and i want to hide or redirect it @UdhayanNair

Comment: you need to go to your .htaccess file. check the document root for me and tell me what your root is

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel provides proper .htaccess, but if you want, you can try with another approach: just make a route for that cases:

```
Route::get('{file_name}.php', 'YourMainController@yourMainAction')
    ->where('file_name', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+');
```